# UIView is shown displaced at the top of the screen

Tags: iphone

OK, hopefully a stupid question from a newbie...

I have an app that used to display fine base on XIB files created in UI Builder.  The .xib still displays fine using the simulator direct from the UIB but when compiled and run, the view is displaced by 40 or 50 pixels (about 1/3 the width of a nav bar) so that I get a bar of white space at the bottom and half my title text hidden on the nav bar at the top.

I have tried fiddling with various parameters for the view and main window (eg layout wants full screen and resize view from NIB) but nothing seems to make any difference.

I tried upgrading xcode from 3 to 4 but no difference.

Any pointers gratefully received...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your specific scenario, but layout problems usually boil down to inappropriately specified autosizing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation:

Fiddling around in Interface Builder, in the typical template xib file, you can get two windows to draw your interface on. One of them refers to the window, the other to the view controller. You should leave the window alone. Anything you put in there is placed relative to the window, i.e. the screen. This would typically lead to what you describe.